# Como formatar uma String ou colocar mascara com Totalcross

Tags: totalcross

Estou utilizando da seguinte maneira, mas não funciona por causa do compilador por usar coisas do javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.

```
public string formatar(String text, String mask) throws ParseException {
    return new MaskFormatter(mask).valueToString(text);
}
```

Não encontrei uma solução na documentação disponível

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução, porém não sei se é a melhor.

Utilizando a mascara do próprio totalcross.ui.Edit, o método ficou da seguinte forma:

```
public string formatar(String text, String mask) {
    Edit edit = new Edit(mask);
    edit.setMode(Edit.NORMAL, true);
    edit.setText(text);
    return edit.getText();
}
```